# Android ClassCastException Object[] to String[]

Tags: android, classcastexception

Hey fellow programmers <3
I want to transfer an String Array from my Service to my MainActivity via broadcastReceiver.
 The String Array is wrapped in an Intent.
 But when I try to get the String[] out of my intent
 then it is an Array of Objects and I can´t just use intent.getStringArrayExtra(String).
 Then I tried this:

How to convert object array to string array in Java?
`String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(objectArray, objectArray.length, String[].class);`

But it doesen`t work either :/

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
final String LOG_TAG = "mainActivityLogs";
Button btnStartService;

private int numberOfFinishedTasks = 0;
private List<String> finishedTasksInTheLast60Sec = new ArrayList<>();
private int startedTasks = 0;
private ProgressBar pbService;
private Handler progressHandler = new Handler();

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //results in java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
        finishedTasksInTheLast60Sec = Arrays.asList(intent.getStringArrayExtra("finishedTasks"));

        //results in java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
        Object[] objectArray = intent.getStringArrayExtra("finishedTasks");
        String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(objectArray, objectArray.length, String[].class);
        finishedTasksInTheLast60Sec = Arrays.asList(stringArray);

        numberOfFinishedTasks += finishedTasksInTheLast60Sec.size();
        for (String finishedTask : finishedTasksInTheLast60Sec) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, finishedTask);
        }
    }
};
```

This function is in Service file MyService and var finishedTasks just contains name of Threads which are closed:

```
   private void sendBroadcast(List<String> finishedTasks) {
   Intent intent = new Intent("myServiceUpdate");
   intent.putExtra("finishedTasks", finishedTasks.toArray());
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
   }
```

I hope you can help and if you need the whole code just text me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While sending, cast the List type to ArrayList type by:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("finishedTasks",(ArrayList<String>)finishedTasks);
```

While receiving just get the data by :

```
 List stringList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("finishedTasks");
```

Comment: intent.putStringArrayListExtra("finishedTasks",(ArrayList<String>)finishedTasks); was really helpful^^ thanks a lot :)